# Contact form 7- dynamically create input fields

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 plugin. I want to add input fields like text box dynamically into form. I have following code but not sure how to use it in contact form 7.

```
<script>
$('#myTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
$('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="fname" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td></tr>')
});
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" style="border: 1px solid black">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="fname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="fname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="fname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Insert row">
</p>
```